# Using Mycroft with internal server for audio books

Tags: artificial-intelligence, mp3, voice-recognition

I have an aging mother with poor eyesight and would like to create a voice interface to search, inform and read books to her. We have an extensive audiobook library and want to avoid Kindle and other web services that are pay services. She gets confused with the cd player and can not read the titles on the cds.

I am looking to Mycroft to act as a voice interface to play(read) an internal server with 500 audiobooks on it. I have not seen the skills that would take me to a very elegant solution. My initial thought was to use empy with a playlist that would be named Cooking, History, Mystery, and so on. The artist would be the author, Album would be the name of the book and the genre would be categories like Cooking or History. I would like to have the audio search find and state the options in each category, name the author and title, and possibly a short summary of the book.
I have reviewed the skills in mycraft marketplace and do not see a clear line of site for these requirements.
I am looking for suggestions as many skills that might be available and then I will have to create additional ones to get all to work together.

Thoughts and suggestions

Kindest Regards..

Currently looking for suggestions. The skills I plan on loading are the basic SDK and playing MP3s. Any additional suggestions would be grateful. I will post progress on my GitHub account.